# Copying a file from S3 into my codebase when using Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have the following script:

```
Parameters:
  bucket:
    Type: CommaDelimitedList
    Description: "Name of the Amazon S3 bucket that contains your file"
    Default: "my-bucket"
  fileuri:
    Type: String
    Description: "Path to the file in S3"
    Default: "https://my-bucket.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/oauth-private.key"
  authrole:
    Type: String
    Description: "Role with permissions to download the file from Amazon S3"
    Default: "aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role"

files:
  /var/app/current/storage/oauth-private.key:
    mode: "000600"
    owner: webapp
    group: webapp
    source: { "Ref" : "fileuri" }
    authentication: S3AccessCred

Resources:
  AWSEBAutoScalingGroup:
    Type: "AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup"
    Metadata:
      AWS::CloudFormation::Authentication:
        S3AccessCred:
          type: "S3"
          roleName: { "Ref" : "authrole" }
          buckets: { "Ref" : "bucket" }
```

The issue that I am having is that when this is being deployed, the file aren't present in the `/var/app/current/storage` directory.

I thought that maybe this script was running too soon and the `current` directory wasn't ready yet, so I tried the `ondeck` directory and this also doesn't work.

If I change the path to anywhere other than my codebase directory it works, the file is copied from S3.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directives under the "files" key are processed before your web application is set up. You will need to download the file to a tmp file, and then use a `container_command` to transfer it to your app in the current directory.

This [AWS doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html) mentions near the top the order in which keys are processed. The `files` key is processed before `commands`, and `commands` are run before the application and web server are set up. However, the `container_commands` section notes that they are used "to execute commands that affect your application source code".

So you should modify your script to something like this:

```
Parameters: ...
Resources: ...

files:
  "/tmp/oauth-private.key":
    mode: "000600"
    owner: webapp
    group: webapp
    source: { "Ref" : "fileuri" }
    authentication: S3AccessCred

container_commands:
  file_transfer_1:
    command: "mkdir -p storage"
  file_transfer_2:
    command: "mv /tmp/oauth-private.key storage"
```

Comment: This is perfect. Did the trick. I pretty sure you need to be a robot to understand and navigate through the AWS docs. So many contradicting articles. 

Although, just one amendment. `file_transfer_3` is not required as `mv` deletes it already.

Comment: Ah yes, I'll fix that. I think I was copying from one of my examples that used `cp` for some reason. Glad this helped!

Comment: Spot on! Thanks again!

Comment: Works for deployment, but an error on the ElasticBeanstalk configuration update. From eb-engine.log `[INFO] Error occurred during build: Command file_transfer_2 failed`