# How to deploy GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS and use from Django app deployed using Elasticbeanstalk

Tags: django, firebase, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an Django app deployed to AWS using Elasticbeanstalk.

I implemented FCM(Firebase Cloud Messaging) relation to Django app. To access FCM feature from Django, it required Firebase Admin SDK installed to django.  Firebase Admin SDK requires firebase's private key as json file accessed via env var GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS.

On my local Mac Book env I set local path to private key json file to GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS in .bash_profile.

How do I deploy the firebase's privatge key json file to somewhere safe on AWS(S3 maybe) and access from Django app deployed to AWS using Elasticbeanstalk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Store the private key file in S3, then use `.ebextensions` to securely download it to your application. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53991672/1753903) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61199356/1753903) as examples.
2. Set the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS in the Elastic Beanstalk console: Go to the environment, click on Configuration, go to Modify Software, and then enter the environment variable, with the value being the path to the credentials file.